# vba web form box after click

Tags: vba, input, webforms, box

I want to automatically fill a web form with VBA and I have this problem:
On the webpage there is a radio button and when I click it there is a text box appearing beneath tha button. I want to insert text into this text box, but it just doesn't work with VBA code.

I tried multiple codes, but the text just doesn't appear.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
Set allhyperlinks = ie.Document.getelementsbytagname("input")
For Each hyper_link In allhyperlinks
    If hyper_link.getattribute("id") = "file_import_type_remote" Then
        hyper_link.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

With this code, the radio button is checked and the additional input box appears.
The input box has this code:

```
<div class="fr-fieldset">
<p>URL: <input type="text" name="file_import_remote" size="40" class="txt" style="width: 20em;" value="http://" /> </p>
</div>
```

The code I tried to use for filling the input box is:

```
Set allhyperlinks = ie.Document.getelementsbytagname("input")
For Each hyper_link In allhyperlinks
    If hyper_link.getattribute("name") = "file_import_remote" Then
        hyper_link.setattribute("value") = "MyURL"
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I also tried:

```
Call ie.Document.getElementById("file_import_remote").setattribute("value", "MyURL")
```

No luck...
Please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what is not behaving as expected?  Is an error being raise and if so at what line of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect what is happening is that your code clicks the radio button to load the text box then searches for the text box *before the text box has actually loaded*.  You will need to implement some method to pause your code or wait until the text box is loaded.

There are multiple ways to do this.

#### 1) Ask IE

Use Internet Explorers `readyState` and `Busy` properties to see if it is rendering or loading a page.

```
While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE <> 4 And ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
```

I have found this to not be reliable with dynamic web pages.

#### Hard Sleep

The simplest solution is to declare the sleep function by placing this at the top of your module

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

And insert a hard sleep call between clicking the radio buttons and accessing the textbox

```
Sleep 1000 ' sleep 1 second
```

Obviously this will slow down your code and if it doesn't wait long enough it will break again as it did before.

#### Attempt to Find

This one is more complex but will return the htmlObject as soon as it is found.  First we abstract the method to just search for an element by it's attribute.

```
Public Function SafeGetHtmlObject(ByVal elements As Object, _
        ByVal attrName As String, ByVal value As String) As Object

    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In elements
        If element.getAttribute(attrName) = value Then
             Set HtmlObjectExists = element
             Exit Function
        End If
    Next element

    Set HtmlObjectExists = Nothing

Exit Function
```

Then we attempt to get that object.  If the object was not found, we continue to look for it until it is found.  I recommend that you implement an Optional TimeOut variable so that if the object never loads we don't get caught in an infinite loop.

```
Public Function WaitForHtmlObjectBeforeGetting(ByVal ie As Object, _
        ByVal tagName As String, ByVal attrName As String, _
        ByVal value As String) As Object

    Dim soughtHTMLObject As Object
    Do
        Dim htmlElements As Object
        Set htmlElements = ie.document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)

        Set soughtHTMLObject = SafeGetHtmlObject(htmlElements, attrName, value)

        DoEvents

    Loop While soughtHTMLObject Is Nothing

    Set WaitForHtmlObjectBeforeGetting = soughtHTMLObject
    ' recommended that you raise an error here if it still doesn't exist

End Function
```

---

#### Other notes

> ```
> For Each hyper_link In allhyperlinks
>     If hyper_link.getattribute("id") = "file_import_type_remote" Then
>         hyper_link.Click
>         Exit For
>     End If
> Next
> ```

Can be replaced with `ie.Document.getElementById("file_import_type_remote")`

Comment: I tried Ask IE and Hard sleep, they don't work. For the third option, I don't know how to call the function in my code.

Comment: I really don't know ehat happened, but when I retried my initial code it worked! Thanbks!